# php OOP objects/classed return values

Tags: php, syntax

So say I have the following code,

```
$obj = new foo();
echo $obj;
```

---

```
class foo {
    public function __construct()
    {
        return 'a';
    }
}
```

How do I make $obj echo the string 'a'?

How do I make $obj refer to or equal what is returned by the object/class?

Need to return a value from a __construct(), and also a normal private function within another class. For example:

```
$obj2 = new foo2();
echo $obj2;
```

---

```
class foo2 {
    public function __construct()
    {
        bar();
    }

    private bar() 
    {
        return 'a';
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I just want to mention here that this is highly uncommon(even if possible) and I cant think of any use case at all why someone would need that.

Comment: did you at least TRY to read the fine manual before posting this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the magic __toString() method to convert your class to a representing string.
You should not return something in your constructor, __toString() is automaticly called if you try to use your instance as string (in case of echo).

from php.net:

```
<?php
// Declare a simple class
class TestClass
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

$class = new TestClass('Hello');
echo $class;
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Answer (score 2):

Constructors in PHP are more like initialisation functions; their return value is not used, unlike JavaScript for instance.

If you want to change the way objects are normally echoed you need to provide the magic `__toString()` method:

```
class foo 
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->value = 'a';
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

A private method that would return the value can be used in a similar manner:

```
class foo2
{
    private function bar()
    {
        return 'a';
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->bar();
    }
}
```